# How to override back key pressed in android sherlock fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I want to override backkey press event and replace current sherlock fragment by previous sherlock fragment. I didn't find any way of doing this. I'm not sure whether it is possible or not. 
I used following method but it didn't work,

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the complete code for the sherlock fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

 public class MyTasksFragment extends SherlockFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mytask_fragment_layout, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
   }
  }
```

Can any one please tell me how to do this if it is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

on `onCreateView` methode add this code

```
getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go back to the previous fragment using this code on the parent activity.
Override onbackpresssed function on the parent activity.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
      if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
      else
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Also change your fragment transaction code to :

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```